# Any jquery/javascript graph that can load more than 200000 records

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, graph

I have to display area graph for products and their popularity .But i have more than 5000 in some categories , so please let me know if their is any way to display these record-set.

Comment: Let's try and think why. Displaying 200k records in a graph, do you think it as plausible?

Comment: What have you tried? Do you want to display 200 000 points our just let the 200 000points be the base data for the graph? In the latter case you could just get the 10 representational points by taking average or smth like that.

Comment: not sure it will do the trick but have a look at this:    its not javascript/jquery but might help you: http://www.maani.us/xml_charts/

Answer (score 1):

Can you not do some averaging / some other processing of the data before making the graph data?